# gnuplot crash after negative values

Tags: gnuplot, negative-number

I am trying to plot data with errors e.g 
`-1.4 -0.2 0.4 6.1 2.5 5.2`
I used `plot 'data.txt' u 1:4:($1-$2):($1+$3):($4-$6):($4+$5) w xyerrorbars`
After it, my plot looks ok for yerror but in xerror not. Points are in good spots but errors are shifted.
I tried to use `set format xdata "%f"` and so on but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the actual meaning of you columns? A negative error makes indeed no sense. For `xyerrorbars` you can either specify a single `xdelta` or `xlow` and `xhigh`.

Comment: order of columns are: xvalue, upper xdelta, lower xdelta, y value, upper ydelta, lower ydelta. 
Errors are nonaxisymmetric 

[link] (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node140.html)  I used it lately and it works for **non** negative values. Now I can use it only for `y values` but I need `x` too

Comment: I understand that, but what sense does `upper delta = -0.2` make? By definition of the columns for `xyerrorbars`, all error values must be positive. How the value must be interpreted, if it lowers the x-value, or raises it, is solely contained in the fact, that you specify a value as `low` or `high` error delta.

Comment: I think I see what I done wrong. Thanks
I should have xdelta or ydelta without negative values because I am using formula like `plot 'data.txt' u 1:4:($1-$2):($1+$3):($4-$6):($4+$5) w xyerrorbars`